# How to get angular controller reference from compiled element in unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive

After giving up on ngMockE2E being able to supply proper passThrough() from the $httpBackend, I've resorted to adding the templates to the cache manually. This seems to work great, if I want to just 'test' my template. However, say I want to test some conditions on the controller that get invoked (via directive), how do a I get a reference to it?

```
describe('RedactedFilter ', function() {

    var ctrl, filterModel,createController;

    var $httpBackend,$scope,template, $templateCache,$compile,$rootScope, $compile;

    beforeEach(module('RedactedApp.Services'));
    beforeEach(module('RedactedApp.Controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('RedactedApp.Models'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache,_$compile_,_$rootScope_) {

        //assign the template to the expected url called by the directive and put it in the cache
        template = $templateCache.get('src/main/app/components/redactedFilter/redacted-filter.tpl.html');
        $templateCache.put('src/main/app/components/redactedFilter/redactedFilter-filter.tpl.html',template);

        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));



    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope,_$q_, $injector, _$compile_) {

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $compile = _$compile_;

        filterModel = $injector.get('RedactedFilterModel');
    }));

    it('should default to tab 0', function() {

        var formElement = angular.element('<redacted-filter></redacted-filter>');
        var element = $compile(formElement)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        var ctrl = element.controller();

        //ctrl is undefined
        expect(ctrl.selectedTab).toEqual(0);
    });

});
```

Note that it does not say function controller() is undefined, but the result of calling it. My directive has `replace` set to `false` so I don't think it's an issue with the transclusion hiding the element.

Here's my directive for good measure:

```
angular.module('RedactedApp.Directives').directive('redactedFilter', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            templateUrl: '../../main/app/components/redactedFilter/redacted-filter.tpl.html'
        };
    });
```

Comment: You should not need access to the directive's controller. You are applying the compiled directive against a scope, you could check the scope to see if the values you are expecting have been set.

Comment: I get undefined in that case, since I use controller as, instead of relying on scope. I think the better way is to compile the element and shove it into an explicit controller ref?

Comment: Just because you're using controller as does not mean you're not using $scope, it is just not being injected in. In your case above since you're applying your directive to $rootScope, I would check for the value of `selectedTab` to be defined on $rootScope. (Side note: I would use $rootScope.$new() instead of $rootScope)

Comment: Well, I think I missed a big step here, I have to pre-process the template then shove it in the cache. This does not actually load it =(. I really wish they'd fix the passThrough so we can load templates like a sane person. Or am I missing something?

Comment: To handle the external templates I use [karma-ng-html2js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787697/how-to-get-angular-controller-reference-from-compiled-element-in-unit-tests)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. Management wants to ALSO use jasmine runner, so only solves for half. This is what Angular needs to fix. the issue has been open forever. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1434

Comment: "you could check the scope to see if the values you are expecting have been set." how would I use a spy on the controller?

Answer (score 0):

First, use ng-html2j or ng-templates to shove your templates into your template cache before you run tests.

Then compile the templates into elements, and shove them into your controller for testing:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache,_$compile_,_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {

    //get the template from the cache
    template = $templateCache.get('src/main/app/components/someController/widget-search.tpl.html');

    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    //compile it
    element = $compile(template)($rootScope);
}));

 //then shove your compiled element into your controller instance



it( 'should be instantiated since it does not do much yet', function(){

            ctrl = $controller('SomeController',
                {
                    $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
                    $element: element
                });

            expect( ctrl.hasInstance).toBeTruthy();

        });
```